# CASE Statement in WHERE Clause (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using `Case` statement in `WHERE` clause for SQL Server. However, the values I have in `THEN` clause is a list of integer. Is there any other way of doing this in a `WHERE` clause?  OrderIds are in drop-down list, so either 30, 40 or 50 is selected of it none is selected, then orderID IN (30, 40, 50). P.S. I can't do @OrderID IS NULL otherwise it will search for every orderid in the database. So either one value or default (30,40,50)

```
WHERE 
    1 = 1
    AND [Order].[ORDERID] IN 
        (CASE WHEN @ORDERID IS NOT NULL
            THEN @ORDERID 
        ELSE
            THEN ('30,40,50')
        END)
```

I keep getting an error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '30,40,50' to data type int

Comment: You are missing the word `THEN` in your case statement

Comment: Since it seems you have a multi-select combobox you have one of two choices. Either pass in a table valued parameter with the selected values OR you going to have to use dynamic sql.

Comment: Try [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48470166/case-statement-in-where-clause-sql-server/#48470415)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use a `case` *expression*.  Just use basic logic:

```
WHERE 1 = 1 AND
      (@OrderId IS NULL OR [Order].OrderId in (30, 40, 50))
```

I would also advise you to name your tables so they do not conflict with SQL keywords.  Your table could be named `Orders` for instance.

Also, I assume the string representation for the list is unnecessary.  Otherwise, that introduces other issues (if you are representing a list as a string).

EDIT:

I'm worried that the actual logic you want is:

```
WHERE 1 = 1 AND
      ((@OrderId IS NULL AND [Order].OrderId in (30, 40, 50)) OR
       ([Order].OrderId = @OrderId)
      )
```

This works, as long as you have a single value in `@OrderId`.

Comment: I updated my description, for using Case WHEN THEN, it mandates me for using list as string. And like it said @OrderID could be either one value or by default 3 values in the list

Comment: For the 2nd snippet, I think the `@OrderId = @OrderId` should be `@OrderId = [Order].OrderId`

Answer (score 0):

`CASE` expressions result in **values**. You can't use them to produce *expressions*, such as the value list expression you're trying to use. You need to re-think how you structure this so you can just use a value.

One way to do this is to split the case expression so each possible `WHEN` result is it's own condition, and the alternative result from each condition will produce `true`:

```
WHERE 
    1 = 1
    AND [Order].[ORDERID] = coalesce(@ORDERID, [Order].[ORDERID])
    AND case when @orderid is null then [Order].[ORDERID] ELSE 30 end IN (30, 40, 50)
```

There's usually a simpler way to write the expression, but this illustrates a reliable way to make the conversion from incorrect CASE to correct WHERE.

Answer (score 0):

If your numbers are a *comma separated string of numbers*, you can use this code:

```
DECLARE @LIST VARCHAR(200)
SET @LIST = '30, 40, 50'

---------------------------
WHERE 1 = 1 AND
     (
      @OrderId IS NULL
      OR
      [Order].OrderId in (SELECT * FROM dbo.SplitStrings_Moden(@LIST,N','))
     )
```

To use the above code you need to define the following function in your DB to get a Table from comma separated string of numbers:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings_Moden
(
   @List NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN
  WITH E1(N)        AS ( SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 
                         UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 
                         UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1),
       E2(N)        AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b),
       E4(N)        AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b),
       E42(N)       AS (SELECT 1 FROM E4 a, E2 b),
       cteTally(N)  AS (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT TOP (DATALENGTH(ISNULL(@List,1))) 
                         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E42),
       cteStart(N1) AS (SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t
                         WHERE (SUBSTRING(@List,t.N,1) = @Delimiter OR t.N = 0))
  SELECT Item = SUBSTRING(@List, s.N1, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@List,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000))
    FROM cteStart s;
```

Comment: This is not a good piece of code for splitting strings. Looping is not needed for this and it going to be horrific for performance. Here are several far better choices for this. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: Thank you @SeanLange for your valuable note. I replaced the function in my answer with the function that presented by _Jeff Moden_ for this issue to has better performance.

Comment: The Jeff Moden DelimitedSplit8K is my personal choice as a splitter.